# Как проверить длину пароля?

Tags: php, пароль

```
echo strlen('абвг').'<br />';
echo strlen('abcd').'<br />';
```

Всем привет!

Первая строка возвращает 8, вторая 4 (там типа 2 байта русский символ занимает, или что то такое, да?). Как получить реально количество символов в строке?

Comment: mb_strlen()

Comment: @lampa Все равно тоже самое

Comment: Опять к вопросу о минусовании.

--

Мне кажется, что если минусовать все вопросы, связанные с непониманием простых вещей, то спрашивать о сложных (и видимо интересных, с нетерпением ожидаемых желающими ответить) скоро будет просто некому.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну неужели так сложно?! Укажи кодировку, никто же не знает входную её, она автоматом ставится в "по умолчанию"

```
mb_strlen('абвг','UTF-8');
```

Comment: Да, это то , что нужно :)

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что английские буквы, а также спец. символы закодированы в 1 байт(8 бит), а буквы и символы других алфавитов - двумя байтами(16 бит). Поэтому asd - 3 байта, а ыбй - 6 для strlen(тут считается не кол-во символов, а кол-во байт). Вам нужно подключить **extension=php_mbstring.dll** в файле **php.ini**, в самом начале файла написать **mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');** и использовать для вычисления длины строки - **mb_strlen**.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно указать кодировку, например UTF-8

```
echo mb_strlen('абвг','UTF-8').'<br />';
```